# Can't inherit properties from parent constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not really sure how to ask this. I have at least a couple of files.

Question.js:

```
class Questions {

  constructor(questions) {
    super();
    this.questions = questions;
  }

  startUp() {
    console.log(this.questions);
  }
}
```

Answers.js:

```
class Answers {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.addQuestions();
  }

  addQuestions() {
    this.question = new Questions();
  }
}
```

What I want to happen is to somehow inherit this.questions from the constructor and display it in the console from startUp(), but I always get "undefined". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: is `new Question()` a typo ? ( singular, no `s` )

Comment: Also if it's meant to be `Questions`, your not sending anything to the constructor, so `this.questions` will be undefined.  Currently your code does't really make much sense yet, if your wanting to maintain a list of questions then your will need to store them somewhere, have a look into Arrays..

Comment: You can't call `super()` in a class that doesn't inherit from another class.

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code

1. You are calling `super()` in `class` which is not inherited
2. You are not passing anything to `Questions` questions constructor so `new Questions()` will return and object with `questions:undefined`
3. You are missing `s` at end of `Question`

```js
class Questions {
  constructor(questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
  }

  startUp() {
    console.log(this.questions);
  }
}
console.log(new Questions())
class Answers {
  constructor() {
     this.addQuestions();
  }

  addQuestions() {
    this.questions = new Questions(["Question 1","Question2"]);
  }
}
let x = new Answers();
x.addQuestions();
x.questions.startUp();
```